# How do you plot multiple bars (each bar representing a column) that show the average value of numerical values of a column in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, geom-bar

I have four columns that contain numberical values (hundreds of rows). I would like to plot a bar chart that shows the average value of each of those columns on one chart. So it would show 4 bars on one bar chart, and each bar would represent one column.

Columns are veryactive, fairlyactive, lightlyactive, sedentary. I already know the mean for each column with the summary function, but I want to plot it on a chart. Do I need another variable for one of the other axis?

I was able to plot one of the columns in a bar chart and showing calories as the x axis, but I would just like to compare the mean for each column within a bar chart.

```
ggplot(Activity_Zero, aes(x = calories, y = veryactive))+
  stat_summary(geom = 'bar', fun.y = 'mean')
```

Here is a sample of my data:
[tibble of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0e40.jpg)

Comment: Hello! Could you give us a sample of your data so we can see what it currently looks like? Perhaps `dput(head(Activity_zero))` would give a short example dataframe which you should paste in your question to work with.

Comment: I added an image of a tibble of my data for reference

Comment: Are you looking to compare the means across each of the four columns - veryactive, fairlyactive, lightlyactive, sedentary - or the means somehow linked to calories? Not sure what you mean by the calories column in your example. Also, best way to share code is not an image but some code to reconstruct a dataframe. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on posting good questions

Comment: Thank you, I'll reread the post on making good questions. I'm new and trying to navigate my new life in R. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your data are formatted. I've provided two examples below.

If you're starting with a table with the summary values, you can do this

```r
library(ggplot2)

levels <- c("veryactive", "fairlyactive", "lightlyactive", "sedentary")
df1 <- data.frame(activitylevel = factor(levels, levels = levels),
                 meancalories = c(3000, 2500, 2000, 1500))
ggplot(df1, aes(x = activitylevel, y = meancalories)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And if you're starting with your original data in long form, you can do this.

```r
library(ggplot2)
levels <- c("veryactive", "fairlyactive", "lightlyactive", "sedentary")
df2 <- data.frame(activitylevel = factor(rep(levels,
                                     each = 20), levels = levels),
                 calories = c(rnorm(20, 3000, 100),
                              rnorm(20, 2500, 100),
                              rnorm(20, 2000, 100),
                              rnorm(20, 1500, 100))
                 )
ggplot(df2, aes(x = activitylevel, y = calories)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "col", fun = "mean")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Finally, if you're starting with your data in wide form (i.e. a column for each activity level) then I'd suggest you look up the function `tidyr::pivot_longer`, which will wrangle your data into the form required for `stat_summary`.

Comment: Thanks! The first example worked for me and I understand its process the most. I hope I can improve more to understand the other processes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `colMeans`

```
cols <- c("veryactive", "fairlyactive", "lightlyactive", "sedentary")
```

```
# base R
barplot(colMeans(Activity_Zero[, cols]))
```

```
# ggplot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(stack(colMeans(Activity_Zero[, cols])), aes(ind, values)) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to pivot your data like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  sedentary = sample(10:50, 100, replace = TRUE),
  lightlyactive = sample(10:20, 100, replace = TRUE),
  fairlyactive = sample(100:400, 100, replace = TRUE),
  veryactive = sample(300:600, 100, replace = TRUE),
  calories = sample(1500:2500, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(c(veryactive, fairlyactive, lightlyactive, sedentary), 
               names_to = "group",
               values_to = "vals") |> 
  ggplot(aes(fct_inorder(group), vals)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean)
```

[image]